# Add game-like animations to web app

Tags: html, css, flash, animation

I want to add game like effects to a web app to make it more interactive and fun for the user. Specifically, when someone fills out an answer, I want to have a little character that does a dance, or gold coins pop out - something similar to what you would see in a game.

What is the best way to do this? I'm a little confused on if this is possible through HTML5, or if I still need to work with Flash, or what. I'm not sure of the terminology to use to search for the answer, and so far I've found CSS3 animations and HTML5 vector animations but these aren't exactly what I'm looking for.

I would appreciate any insight, even on just what terms to search for!

Thanks,
Heather

Comment: Well you will need javascript or jquery to catch some event like: completing the quiz or filling the right answer. Then you can chose from many possibilities like GIF animation, CSS3 animation, JQ/JS animation :) But i think for u is GIF or CSS3 the best solution. I dont have the time now to answer this properly.. sorry but just learn how to make a simple css animation and then you just need to have a hidden div and afer your event you will show that div and you will add a animated class to it :) simple as fuc* I hope i helped a little :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options:

**CSS:** check this animations effects, and use them wherever you want: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Do not only use them: analyze each animation and learn how do they work. As you see CSS can be quite powerful on animation and does not need much memory to run (important for mobile devices)

**jQuery:** Once you have get familiar with CSS animations and possibilities, check all the `.animation` method posibilities [from jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Its a good way to start.

About very specific and complex things like advanced text animations, I suggest you to search for specific plugins created right for those pruposes. For example, [Textillate](https://jschr.github.io/textillate/) for text animations, [WaitMe](http://vadimsva.github.io/waitMe/) for load animations or [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) for loading effects and loading processes.

To finish with, sources like [Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/) are great not ony on downloadable CSS and jQuery code for, for example, [button effets](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/), but also as a inspirational source.

Have fun, and always try to inspire yourself, and learn required knowledgements to develop your own effects before copying code.

Comment: Thank you!! This is extremely helpful, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that you must check the answer that better solves your question, for any question you make on StackOverflow. You have to tick on the ✓ mark on the left of the anwer you choose as best, in this case I guess mine. Here you have a brief explanation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Ah yes, done. Thanks!